# How to check @pattern annotation for a string 2-2E454

Tags: java, regex, annotations, bean-validation

How to check @pattern annotation for a string that includes alphanumeric and - like (1-1k546) .

Comment: You question is very vague.  Please be more specific and see this help:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi Rudy how to check @pattern for a string that includes alphanumeric and "-"    like (1-1k546)

Comment: @Pattern(regexp ="^[0-9a-zA-Z.,\'_+*()?;:\"&!$%#@=|{}[]\\/®™©-]*$"). getting constarintvalidationexception how to fix it?

Comment: Please open a new question and show the code that you are running and where the error is produced.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795395/validation-error-for-pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\d-[0-9a-zA-Z]+

\d match a digit [0-9]
- matches the character - literally
[0-9a-zA-Z]+ match a single character present in the list below
    Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
    a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
    A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
```