# validation error for @pattern

Tags: regex, rest, annotations, bean-validation

Getting validation error for

```
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
@Pattern(regexp ="^[0-9a-zA-Z,.\'_+*()?;\"!$%#@={}]$[\\/®™©|&-]*$")
private String testListName;
```

I am passing the testlist name in json format to create a resource using restservice. and getting validation error.

```
{"testListName":"longlist"}
```

Comment: Your regex parses into two classes `^ [0-9a-zA-Z,.\'_+*()?;"!$%#@={}] $ [\/®™©|&-]* $` with a EOS marker between them.

Comment: To get a single class you'd have to escape the inner square brackets: `^[0-9a-zA-Z,.\'_+*()?;"!$%#@={}\]$\[\/®™©|&-]*$` Or, if you intend for two classes, remove the inner EOS marker `$` or put it inside one of the classes, or if needed between the two classes, escape it `\$` or put it inside a class by itself `[$]`. Reason being, the dollar sign is a regex metacharacter if not used as a literal.

Comment: I want to get it as single class but when I escape square brackets in regex I am getting invalid escape  sequence as compilation error

Comment: That's because you have to double escape them for the language parser: `"^[0-9a-zA-Z,.'_+*()?;\"!$%#@={}\\]$\\[/®™©|&-]*$"` which sends this `^[0-9a-zA-Z,.'_+*()?;"!$%#@={}\]$\[/®™©|&-]*$` to the regex engine. Now it's a single class.

Comment: Thanks for the now I am getting validation errors for trademark copyright symbols

Comment: See if has a Unicode modifier you can add to the regex as a parameter. Or, you can try to stick in the _Uincode_ escape sequence `\uXXXX` and see if that works. `"^[0-9a-zA-Z,.'_+*()?;\"!$%#@={}\\]$\\[/\\u00AE\\u2122\\u00A9|&-]*$"`